# JQGrid - encoding problem - works only in firefox (not in chrome and explorer)

Tags: xml, encoding, jqgrid, character-encoding

My xml file to load into the JQGrid is UTF8 encoded.
Now, when I'm using Firefox, I can see the data in the grid,
but if it is Chrome or Explorer, I can't see the data.

I changed the xml file to ANSI encoding, and it worked for me.
The problem I have to use UTF8 encoding.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that using CDATA tags were the best way to get XML to work in JQgrid:

```
 echo "<cell><![CDATA[" . $row['pre_date'] . "]]></cell>";
```

if you're using something like PHP to generate the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't send the correct header to IE - and it will work without CDATA tags:

`header('Content-type: application/json; Charset=utf8;');`

[see my blog for the solution](http://www.codefx.biz/2011/02/jquery-json-internet-explorer)